# Service pattern entity framework asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to do unit testing in my asp.net mvc entity framework 6 project and it forced me to look at my code. I had my controllers exposed to my context and decided I should probably separate it out. I was initially looking at the repository/UoW pattern but after reading a lot I decided on the simple service pattern with DI (i.e., the controller is injected with a service that has `GetProducts()`, `FindProduct()`, etc.).

My question is related to the change tracking in this pattern. Before I would just call `SaveChanges()` after a lot of things were done in a controller method, but separating everything made methods like these:

```
 public void AddRequest(Request request)
    {
        using (PricedNotesContext ctxt = new PricedNotesContext())
        {
            ctxt.Requests.Add(request);
            ctxt.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

 public void DeleteRequestData(BaseRequestData reqData)
    {
        using (PricedNotesContext ctxt = new PricedNotesContext())
        {
            ctxt.RequestData.Remove(reqData);
            ctxt.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

In the above you see that `SaveChanges()` is called twice. But I only want it called once. I only want my changes to persist if both operations completed successfully. Is the recommended solution to just have a method called `SaveChanges()` and `Dispose()` which obviously calls `SaveChanges()` and `Dispose()` exposed to the controller to manage the transaction?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest you read about unit of work. Instantiate unit of work / context in your application/business layer only once, instead of each time in a data layer component. And even better, inject it.

Comment: yeah.  at a minimum you should injecting the PriceNotesContext into your controller instead of instantiating it in every method.  In a web environment, you don't really need unit of work, as the context itself acts like a unit of work.  I would however create a TransactionScope at in BeginRequest and then Commit it at EndRequest.  right now none of your operations are atomic.

Comment: OK that is essentially what I have now. I've done some transaction control albeit just with SaveChanges() in my service method. (The methods in the question are in the service, NOT the controller (which they used to be).

Comment: So, only instantiate the context one time. You do it twice now.

Comment: Yes I will add my solution. One sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service should offer functionality in such a way that the consumer does not have to care about saving the context. Actually, it doesn't know about the context. Why don't you simply do something like:

```
public class EfNotesService : INotesService
{
      public ExecuteSomeBusinessOperation(input parameters here)
      {
            // Validate input parameters

            using (PricedNotesContext ctxt = new PricedNotesContext())
            {
                ctxt.Requests.Add(...);
                ctxt.RequestData.Remove(...);

                // other logic

                ctxt.SaveChanges();
            }
      }
}
```

Or even better, you could also use dependency injection to inject the context at the start of the request and dispose of it at the end of the request. This context is then injected into the constructor of EfNotesService, and you can then just use it without the using statement:

```
public class EfNotesService : INotesService
{
      private readonly PricedNotesContext _ctxt;

      public EfNotesService(PricedNotesContext ctxt )
      {
          _ctxt = ctxt;
      }
      public ExecuteSomeBusinessOperation(input parameters here)
      {
            // Validate input parameters

            _ctxt .Requests.Add(...);
            _ctxt .RequestData.Remove(...);

            // other logic

            _ctxt .SaveChanges();               
      }
}
```

Like this, the same context can span multiple services, and you don't have to worry about creating and disposing the context in these services.

Additionally, in your service operations you can of course use business components or even a domain layer to execute the business logic, instead of doing everything in the service.

And add a global exception handler to gracefully deal with exceptions.

Comment: Yes OK. Thanks. This is very close to what I had. I am currently using DI to inject the context in the service like your example and I will not expose the SaveChanges() but just handle it all in the business operations.

Comment: And there is nothing wrong in handling this logic in one service operation - like this you are really exposing the business intend of the operation instead of simple CRUD operations.

Comment: Yes that was my mistake. I was doing CRUD operations instead of business in my service.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.

```
public class EfNotesService : INotesService
{
    private readonly PricedNotesContext _ctxt = new PricedNotesContext();

    public IEnumerable<Request> GetAllRequests()
    {
        return _ctxt.Requests.ToList();
    }

    public void SaveRequest(Request request)
    {
        _ctxt.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void DeleteRequestData(BaseRequestData reqData)
    {
        _ctxt.RequestData.Remove(reqData);
    }
    // ...
    // Other methods...
    // ...

    // Transaction control
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _ctxt.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ctxt.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It's not UoW or Repository but it's simple and it works well. Plus I get to keep all the 'store' advantages of the DbContext.

Comment: that's not "Transaction Control" in your service. you need to be using a TransactionScope to achieve that.  You need to scope the TransactionScope to the Request because then it wraps all service calls in the same transaction.

Comment: Is it not a bit strange that the consumer of this service needs to actually call SaveChanges()? This data logic should be abstracted out in my opinion. The consumer should just call the required methods, and should not care about calling Save on it.

Comment: That is fair. OK I will look into something else.

Comment: @L-Four exactly

Comment: you're going to want a transaction attribute that sets up the transaction scope that opens see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946247/how-to-save-two-entities-together-using-a-repository-pattern/38948655#38948655

Comment: Alright I disagree. I read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx. Microsoft seems to recommend the transaction but only says if you need it. They argue that SaveChanges() opens and closes the transaction for you. I do, however, agree with L-Four on the fact that SaveChanges should not be called by the consumer. I will fix that.

Comment: Right, but your transactional boundary ends when you call SaveChanges.  So if you call 2 methods on your service in one controller call they are independent and not atomic.  which is why you open the transactionscope at OnActionExecuting

Comment: I see. Now I am not using the repository pattern as in that link you posted Fran, but I suppose it will still work, right? I will try that out. I guess my other option is to create a method that does both things explicitly in a service call but that seems bad.